# One ViewModel for multiple Views or multiple ViewModels for a single View?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android App that trains the ear of the player, by making them replay on guitar whatever they hear from the phone. I made the note (and chord) recognition part the following way: a main thread that displays the information and listens to the buttons, an `AsyncTask` that records the sound and sends the data to be analyzed and another `AsyncTask` that analyzes and determines what notes have been played.

The note recognition is real-time, so I placed the Analyzer `AsyncTask` in a `ViewModel`. The recognized notes and chords are kept in `LiveData` fields, so whenever they change, the main thread (which is represented by the `View`) is notified.

Right now I am working on a game using this recognition, but I intend to make a tuner, too. The game and the tuner will be using the same recognition algorithm.

My question is: How should I approach this? The *game* and the *tuner* will be having their own functionalities, too. Should I keep the Analyzer `ViewModel` separate from the individual *game* and *tuner* `ViewModels`? That would mean that I would use two `ViewModels` for each of those two `Views`. I figure I shouldn't repeat the Analyzer code in both of the individual `ViewModels`, and also I shouldn't write the functions for the *game* **and** for the *tuner* in the same `ViewModel`, because there will be useless code (the *game* will never use individual *tuner* functions).

Comment: You should probably have your common recognition algorithm in your *model* actually (or even in some service layer independant from the model), not in your *viewmodel*. The viewmodel is made to be bound to the view, not to perform business logic like note recognition.

Comment: So you suggest to record and analyze in the model and save the last recognized note (or chord) in a `LiveData` field there. Then `ViewModel` will get that field, and the `View` will get notified. That seems like a good solution.

Comment: That sounds pretty MVVM to me :) The viewmodel would be in charge of sending the record to the model and retrieve the result to expose it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably have your common recognition algorithm in your **`Model`** actually (or even in some service layer independant from the `Model`), not in your **`ViewModel`**. The `ViewModel` is made to be bound to the `View`, not to perform business logic like note recognition.

In this case, the `ViewModel` would be in charge of sending the recordings to the `Model`, which saves them as `LiveData` objects. The `ViewModel` retrieves them and expose them to the `View` as `LiveDataViewModel` objects for example.